# Mudar output no shiny só quando eu mudo o valor no numericInput()

Tags: r, shiny

Eu tenho essa tabela no meu aplicativo shiny.

```
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 5 |
```

Tem uma caixa para escolher uma linha (de 1 a 3), e a partir disso ele printa o valor referente a essa linha.

Também tem uma outra caixa para que eu possa mudar esse valor. Só que a função `numericInput()` pede um valor inicial, então, quando eu seleciono alguma linha ele já muda o output para o valor inicial.

Só que eu quero que esse valor mude só se eu mudar o valor na caixa do `numericInput()`. Eu posso setar o valor inicial para um valor negativo e colocar um `if()` mas não quero dessa forma.

---

Aqui o exemplo:

```
library('shiny')

ui <- fluidPage(

  numericInput('line', 'Line Choice:', value = 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput('number', 'Value Choice:', value = 0),
  textOutput('text')

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({

    df <- data.frame(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c(2, 3, 5))

    output$text <- renderText({

      i <- input$line
      df[i,2] <- input$number

      paste0(df[i,1], ': ', df[i, 2])

    })
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode gerar esse `numericInput` no lado do server, assim pode determinar qual deve ser o valor inicial. Exemplo:

```
library('shiny')

ui <- fluidPage(

  numericInput('line', 'Line Choice:', value = 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  uiOutput("number_ui"),
  textOutput('text')

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    df <- data.frame(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c(2, 3, 5))


    output$number_ui <- renderUI({
      numericInput('number', 'Value Choice:', df[input$line, 2])
    })

    output$text <- renderText({
      i <- input$line
      if(!is.null(input$number))
        df[i,2] <- input$number
      paste0(df[i,1], ': ', df[i, 2])
    })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Mais detalhes [neste artigo](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)

Comment: Valeu Falbel!
Tinha pensado em algo parecido mas na ui, e obviamente não tinha dado certo.

Comment: Boa!! Essas coisas são chatinhas no shiny... No fim você acaba gerando quase todos os inputs direto no server